# Trigger dependencies in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have developed a pipeline (Pipeline Name: **Data Source**) with a parameter, this pipeline will  run at different frequencies, for example: every 30 minutes or 1 hour or 1 day etc. based on the parameter value.  Now, I have another pipeline (Pipeline Name: **Data Staging**) which is dependent on Pipeline **Data Source** (to complete all of it's frequency runs). Then I also have another Pipeline (Pipeline Name: **Data Mart**) which is dependent on Pipeline **Data Staging**.

I want to orchestrate the above scenario in ADF, so that the dependencies are accounted for while loading individually pipelines.

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

I have started by creating Tumbling Windows triggers (as this is the only trigger where you can specify dependencies).

Trigger A (for Pipeline **Data Source**) --> Runs every 15 minutes but the successive run should only start after **Data Staging** is completed
Trigger B (for Pipeline **Data Source**) --> Runs every 30 minutes but the successive run should only start after **Data Staging** is completed
Trigger C (for Pipeline **Data Source**) --> Runs every 1 hour but should only start after **Data Staging** is completed

After above 3 triggers are completed **Data Staging** will trigger and once it is completed **Data Mart** will trigger.

In the above scenario as there are multiple frequencies I am not sure if the dependencies work correctly. Also I am not sure if Tumbling windows are correct approach for this kind of scenario.

Including an image below to depict above scenario.

[Pipeline Orchestration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3bOv.png)

Any insight or help is much appreciated.

Thanks!